Global sections and meromorphic functions $(H^0(X,L)\setminus \{0\})\to \text{Div}(X))$
In Huybrechts's Complex Geometry, page 82 deals with the map $H^0(X,L) \setminus \{0\} \to \text{Div}(X)$.
If we fix a trivialization on $L$ with the cocycle $(U_i, \psi_{ij})$ and take a non-trivial global section, we can produce a meromorphic function by $f_i := \psi_i(s|_{U_i})$.
Since $\psi_i$ is a trivialization, it is holomorphic, so $f_i := \psi_i(s|_{U_i}) \in \mathcal{O}(U_i)$. Given that $s \neq 0$, then $f_i$ is  a non-vanishing holomorphic function, thus is meromorphic, and so $f_i \in K^*_X(U_i)$.
Huybrechts argues that the reason $f_i$ is meromorphic follows by the identity theorem.
I don't see how we can apply the identity theorem here. What do we mean by that? Is my reasoning wrong?
